# Excel VBA Run-time error ' 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

**Can someone explain to me what's with this code...i'm new to vba codes**

```
Private Sub hide_Click()
'hide the userform
UserForm1.hide
End Sub

Private Sub reset_Click()
'clear the input box
TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""
TextBox3.Value = ""
TextBox4.Value = ""
TextBox5.Value = ""
TextBox6.Value = ""
TextBox7.Value = ""
TextBox8.Value = ""
TextBox9.Value = ""
TextBox10.Value = ""
TextBox11.Value = ""
End Sub

Private Sub submit_Click()
'submit data into the colums
Dim rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4, rng5, rng6, rng7, rng8, rng9, rng10, rng11  As Range

Set rng1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1up).Offset(1, 0)
Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(0, 1)
Set rng3 = rng2.Offset(0, 1)
Set rng4 = rng3.Offset(0, 1)
Set rng5 = rng4.Offset(0, 1)
Set rng6 = rng5.Offset(0, 1)
Set rng7 = rng6.Offset(0, 1)
Set rng8 = rng7.Offset(0, 1)
Set rng9 = rng8.Offset(0, 1)
Set rng10 = rng9.Offset(0, 1)
Set rng11 = rng10.Offset(0, 1)

rng1.Value = TextBox1.Value
rng2.Value = TextBox2.Value
rng3.Value = TextBox3.Value
rng4.Value = TextBox4.Value
rng5.Value = TextBox5.Value
rng6.Value = TextBox6.Value
rng7.Value = TextBox7.Value
rng8.Value = TextBox8.Value
rng9.Value = TextBox9.Value
rng10.Value = TextBox10.Value
rng11.Value = TextBox11.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: After you get the error and you click OK, what in the code is highlighted yellow?

Comment: `x1up` should be `xlup` that is lower case `L` not the number `1`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks worked!!!  I'm new to VBA  actually to the whole Excel thing.......Thanks for noticing the error.

Comment: after submitting, only 4 textbox data were submitted to the sheet. Don't know what could be more wrong.